# Create jump algorithm using sine

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm, game-physics

i am writing a 2D game in C# windows form application.

I want to create Bubble Trouble game, but i'm troubling with the jump algorithm.
I found that i have to use sine function to make it realistic.

There is the ball class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BubbleTrouble
{

    class Ball
    {
        int level,gapX=2,gapY=2,x,y;
        bool up;
        public static int[] levelsPX={0,1,2,3,6,8,9,11};
        Panel panel;
        Graphics gr;

        public Ball(int lvl,int x,int y,bool isUp,Graphics gr)
        {
            this.gr = gr;

            up = isUp;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            if (up)
                gapY = -gapY;

            level = lvl;
        }

        public Ball[] pop()
        {
            if (level == 0)
                return null;
            else
            {
                bool up1 = true; 
                if(y>=20)
                    up1=false;
                Ball first = new Ball(level - 1, x, y,up1,gr);
                Ball second = new Ball(level - 1, first.x + 10 * levelsPX[level-1], y, up1,gr);
                Ball[] a = { first, second };
                level = 0;
                return a;
            }
        }

        public void paint()
        {
            gr.DrawImage(BubbleTrouble.Properties.Resources.ball, x, y, 10 * levelsPX[level], 10 * levelsPX[level]);
        }
        public void getNextPos()
        {
            if ((y <= 0) || (y + 10 * levelsPX[level] >= 364))
            {
                gapY = -gapY;
                up = !up;
            }
            if ((x + 10 * levelsPX[level] >= 681) || (x <= 0))
                gapX = -gapX;
            if (y < 70)
                gapY = -gapY;
            //Math.sin
            x=x+gapX;
            y=y+gapY;

        }

    }
}
```

The ball has X and Y integers, and it also have 2 integers gapX and gapY.
gapX and gapY is used to change the direction of the ball, for example right now the ball is in position (30,30) so in that case, the next position will be (30+gapX,30+gapY), and after this (30+2gapX,30+2gapY) and when the ball is get out of the form bound so the gap change sign. For example if the position on X scale is more then the form bound, the change the gapX to -gapX so the ball will move in the other direction.

But, i want the ball jump in wave and i don't know how to do this using the X Y of the ball and the gapX and gapY.
I found that sine function will help me but i still don't know where and how to use this function.

Please help me i'm trying to figure it out but i don't find any solution.

Thank you,
Asaf.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave, I dont think its a sine wave you want, it sounds more like y = -x^2 (google it) (as a starting point)

Comment: you right but it's not working for example if the X is 30, so the y will be 900, and its out of the form bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small method as a hint. You have to adjust to the height and width of your playground:

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates ball bouncing.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">X position (0 .. 360)</param>
/// <returns>Returns y position (0 .. 1)</returns>
private double Position(double x)
{
    x *= Math.PI / 180;
    return Math.Abs(Math.Cos(x)); // Always positive
}
```